# Scholarship/funding based on publications/research work

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, masters, funding, research-undergraduate

I am an undergraduate senior Mechatronics engineering student looking for a scholarship to pursue a Masters degree next year in Europe (Germany specifically) or US. My current accumulative GPA equates to a C+, however i worked on many research projects, 3 of which were accepted by high impact journals and still working on more to come.

I was wondering if universities would accept my work so far when evaluating my scholarship application? If not, is there a relative number of publications i should achieve in order to apply for a scholarship?

Answer (score 1):

In general, while universities will look for publications, they won't entirely compensate for poor transcripts. Also, there is no "ideal" number of publications here: the more, the better.

With a C+ average, though, you are unlikely to get a scholarship in the US. I should also point out that in central Europe, master's studies don't normally have tuition, and so scholarships aren't normally awarded: you instead need to get funds to support your living expenses.

Comment: With a C+ average, though, you may not be eligible for **admission** to many graduate programs in the US.  Many US graduate schools require a minimum undergraduate GPA of 3.0, and applications below that threshold are often administratively rejected before the admissions committee sees them.